# how to view or make popup a raised request review from administer

Tags: tfs-2015

currently i am doing the study of TFS 2015 for implementing this into my organisation, now i am working in Request review (TFS 2015) portion, here I used to raise a Request review (Code review) option for a receiver  , he already got access rights and he cannot able to see the request what i have sent, please suggest a solution to solve this.

(OR)
Simpler form of my issue:
Any option to POP UP / Open Code Review window in Team Explorer?

Comment: You probably need to add more details to your post if you want someone to be able to help.

Comment: @Yasin How did you request the review? Can you pick up the name of the reviewer when click the drop down arrow to add the reviewer or you just enter the user name directly? Make sure the user name can be picked up automatically. Doubt that the system cannot identify the added reviewer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask for a code review, make sure you have [shared your code in TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs?view=vsts) and the users are added in the team.

1. User A submit a code review and add User B as a reviewer
2. Then User B will find the code review under **My Work** -> **Code Reviews**

Please see [Get your code reviewed with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=vsts) for details

[image]